# How do I import a non-Maven Java project in Netbeans to a Maven project in Eclipse properly?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, netbeans

First I create java project in netbeans and i want to import java project in netbean to maven project in eclipse kepler .I have try it once but, i got error when compile in eclipse kepler.But if l import in java project in eclipse kepler and compile then it work.

Comment: have you created maven project in netbeans?

Comment: no in netbeans is only java project.

Comment: Isn't the question more along the lines, "how do I convert a custom ant project to maven"? I suppose there's a few how-tos on that. Eclipse doesn't have any support for importing netbeans ant projects AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a new maven project in eclipse, notice that you have an src/main/java/ folder
2. Go to your netbeans java project, right-click on 'Source Pakages', click on properties and  copy the location of this folder
3. Go to your files explorer and paste the location, copy all folders under src/
4. return to your maven project in eclipse and paste the folders (actually your java packages) under the src/main/java folder
5. if you used jar libraries just add them to dependencies in the pom.xml